# retain value of counter for particular session even after session logout

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, session, counter

I am making a web application for Data Entry in ASP.Net...
Actually what I am trying to achieve is, I wanna retain value of counter for particular session even after logout.... like if a person is filling form, particular id is assigned to that person and when he/she fills one form counter will set to 1 and so on....and at the end of day counter is 30.

But when the next day that person again fills the form, counter should start from 30...
All this information is stored in Sql database table with the fields Userid and Count which will store the userid and forms filled by that particular person...
basically it is to keep record of how many forms a person has filled..

Hoping for your reply..
Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Simple. You can retrieve the values from the Sql Database Table which you mentioned in your question. If am not wrong, You will store the userid and count at the end of the day. If so you can simply retrieve it from the database.

After login,

```
Protected void Page_load(object sender, Eventargs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String");
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Select count from table where userid = '"+Your field name+"',con);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if(dr.Hasrows)
    {
    while(dr.Read())
    {
       Label1.Text = dr.GetInt32(0).ToString();  // If database structure of count is int and Label1 is your count.
    }
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

Note : This is just a layout. You can proceed in this way. You will find the solution.